# multiplying two dimensional arrays by passing to function

Tags: c++, arrays

I have created the code, and for some reason the elements C[0,3] and C[1,3] are returning the wrong result, although all other elements of the matrix are correct.  Not sure why this is happening.  Thanks!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

const int ROWSA = 4,
      COLSA = 3,
      ROWSB = 3,
      COLSB = 2;


void calc_AB(double [][COLSA], double B[][COLSB], double C[][ROWSA], int,    int, int);
void display_C(double [][ROWSA], int);

int main()
{


    double A[ROWSA][COLSA] = { { 5.2, 1, 9 },
                               { 3.6, 7.5, 0 },
                               { 8, 0, 4.4 },
                               { 0.1, 2.7, 10 } },
    B[ROWSB][COLSB] = { {12, 7.8},
                        {11, 8.9},
                        {10, 0.2} },
    C[COLSB][ROWSA];

    calc_AB(A, B, C, ROWSA, COLSB, COLSA);
    display_C(C, COLSB);

    return 0;
}

void calc_AB(double A[][COLSA], double B[][COLSB], double C[][ROWSA], int ROWSA, int COLSB, int COLSA)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < ROWSA; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < COLSB; j++)
        {
            C[i][j] = 0;
            for (int k = 0; k < COLSA; k++)
            {
                C[i][j] += A[i][k] * B[k][j];
            }
        }
    }
}

void display_C(double C[][ROWSA], int COLSB)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < ROWSA; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < COLSB; j++)
        {
            cout << setw(4) << C[i][j] << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: it displays 136.028 and 370.06 instead of 130.9 and 28.81

Comment: I need your assistance.  My debugger is being upgrade, so I need you to run your debugger and edit your post with the results.

Comment: When i try to run the program, an error message pops up saying: Run-time check failure #2- Stack around the variable 'B' was corrupted

Comment: So, which line is failing?  What are the values of the statement that failed?  Did you use a *debugger* and execute each statement, one at a time (often called *stepping* through a program)?  Please **edit** your post with the results and answers.

Comment: @bturlington and are you sure this is the correct declaration C[COLSB][ROWSA];

Comment: @bturlington aren't these inversed maybe for (int i = 0; i < ROWSA; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < COLSB; j++)
        {

Comment: @bturlington can you tell us more about the logic of your multiplication to be able to understand the problem. Give us an example on how you are calculating the elements of C